# Handling malformed @QueryParam with RESTEasy

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, resteasy, wildfly

I am a bit confused about the Exception handling or lack thereof in RESTEasy with JBoss AS7/Wildfly. I'm not entirely sure in which "domain" the exception handling falls exactly.

This is what I use for testing:

```
@GET
@POST
@Path("/test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response test(@QueryParam("id") final long id) {
    log.info("Incoming request! Wee! With id " + id + "!");

    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

So far, so good. That behaves as expected with localhost/app/rest/test?id=123. However, when I put in something that doesn't 'fit' in the parameter, like localhost/app/rest/test?id=123abc, I get a long exception from RESTEasy, correctly informing me that it doesn't fit into the expected parameter.

But what I don't understand is how I can handle/catch this exception. Obviously, I wouldn't want a 40-line stack trace to go to my main (or any) log, but do proper error logging myself. My research only turned out a generic way to handle all Exceptions of type NumberFormatException, which is totally unsuited for any sane logging approach.

So, how can I handle this issue ? As this happens "outside" my code, I can't exactly surround it with try/catch, and a specific bad parameter for a specific REST mapping isn't really something generic enough to write an application wide Exception mapper.

Comment: Doesn't the server respond with a `4xx` error?

Comment: It doesn't, but I believe that is indeed easily configurable, so I didn't ask about that, since I expect I can handle that part without help. I'm only concerned about the server side handling of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite strange that server doesn't respond with 400 error. If you still want to handle query parameters by yourself you can make a filter and check all query params there.
It shall look like this:

```
@Provider
public class PreResourceFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {     
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = requestContext.getUriInfo().getQueryParameters();
        // here you need to check desired parameters
    }
}
```